# Objective C vs Swift math operations

Tags: objective-c, swift

Performing the following operation in Objective-C and Swift returns different results:

With an input of 23492.4852,

Objective-C function:

```
+ (double)funTest:(double)a {
    return a - (int) a / 360 * 360;
}
```

returns 92.48521

Swift function:

```
class func funTest(a: Double) -> Double {
    return a - Double(Int(a)) / 360 * 360
}
```

returns 0.48521

Does anybody know why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know why the difference?

You've just made a simple grouping error.

As you figured out both Objective-C and Swift require a cast when converting from a floating-point value to an integer one, so you have written `(int)a` for the former and `Int(a)` for the latter.

You have also understood that converting from an integer to a floating-point value differs in the two languages, in Objective-C (and C and lots of other languages) the conversion is *implicit* whereas in Swift it is explicit.

The only mistake you have made is in parsing the Objective-C and hence producing the wrong Swift *or* you've simply mis-typed the Swift.

In arithmetic expressions operators are evaluated according to a priority, relevant to your problem casts bind tightly to the following expression, multiplication and division is done next, then addition and subtraction. What this means is your Objective-C:

```
a - (int) a / 360 * 360
```

is parsed as:

```
a - (double) ( (int) a / 360 * 360 )
```

note that the `(double)` cast applies to the result of the expression `(int) a / 360 * 360`. What you've written in Swift is:

```
a - Double(Int(a)) / 360 * 360
```

which isn't the same, here the cast only applies to `Int(a)`. What you should have written is:

```
a - Double(Int(a) / 360 * 360)
```

which applies the cast to `Int(a) / 360 * 360` just as the Objective-C does.

With that correction in both languages the multiplication and division all operate on integers, and integer division is truncating (e.g. 9 / 4 is 2 not 2.25). With the misplaced parenthesis in Swift the multiplication and division all operate on floating-point values.

TL;DR: You just misplaced a parenthesis.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

The difference is integer vs. floating point division. In integer division, the fractional part is ignored. Some quick examples are `1 / 2 = 0` or `2 / 3 = 0` but `1.0 / 2.0 = 0.5` and `2.0 / 3.0 = 0.67`.

Let's break down how your code works in both languages:

#### Objective-C

Assuming `a = 23492.4852`:

```
a - (int) a / 360 * 360 = a - ((int) a) / 360 * 360
                        = a - 23492 / 360 * 360     // integer division
                        = a - 65 * 360
                        = 23492.4852 - 23400
                        = 92.4852
```

Objective-C inherits [type promotion rules](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html) from C, which can be a lot to remember.

#### Swift

Assuming `a = 23492.4852`:

```
a - Double(Int(a)) / 360 * 360 = a - Double(23492) / 360 * 360  // floating point division
                               = a - 65.2556 * 360
                               = a - 23492
                               = 23492.4852 - 23492
                               = 0.4852
```

In both cases, the compiler has some leeways in interpreting the literal constant of `360`: it can be seen an `int` or `double`.

- I don't know the exact internal workings of the ObjC compiler. You just have to be careful when mixing numeric types in C.
- Swift tries to prevent this confusion by forcing all operands to be of the same data type. Since `a` is `Double`, the only way to interpret `360` is that it must also be a `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to how the compilers see the numbers. Notice in swift you had to explicitly cast `a` into a double after casting it to an `Int`? The swift compiler sees the entire expression as `Double`s so when you do `Double(Int(a)) / 360 * 360` you're getting `23492 / 360 * 360 = 65.25555... * 360 =  23492.4852`. However, in C/C++/Obj-C etc it sees that `23492 / 360` as an int division giving `23492 / 360 * 360 = 65 * 360 =  23400`. And that's where the 90 comes from (from the loss of precision when dividing 2 `int`s in C.